# Running Python Scripts with Argument Name and Value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run a python script from the CMD line with argument and value eg:

```
Question.py   -TA="Text001"  -TB= "Text002"   -TC= "Text003"
```

Is there a way to do that in python ?

Thanks,

Here is my example code

```
import argparse


def TestingArg(Text1,Text2,Text3,):
      print("the text1  is : "+Text1 )
      print("the text1  is : "+Text2 )
      print("the text1  is : "+Text3 )

def Main():
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-TA","Text1",type=str,help="Text ex number 1")
    parser.add_argument("-TB",type=str,help="Text ex number 2")
    parser.add_argument("-TC",type=str,help="Text ex number 3")
    args =parser.parse_args()
    TestingArg(args.Text1,args.Text2,args.Text3)


if __name__=="__main__":
   Main()
```

Comment: Does your code not work? How?

Answer (score -1):

I found my error, thanks for the help

my error was that I had to use `--` in the parser
`parser.add_argument("--TA", type=str, help="Text ex number 1")`

Comment: This will not allow the code in your question to run successfully. `Text1`, `Text2` & `Text3` are not defined anywhere, and you will get an `AttributeError` in the call to `TestingArg()`